# Gdx-pay/openIAB opens google play dialog when configured for Amazon

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, amazon-appstore

I'm developing an android app, and trying to implement IAP via Gdx-Pay (which uses openIAB), however, when the store is set to amazon, when I try to "buy" something from my app, a google play dialog opens. Specifically: "authentication is required. you need to sign in to your google account".

I haven't found anything similar on the internet, so I must be doing something really dumb. Does anyone have any idea what this could be?

Comment: If it makes you feel any better, I have this problem as well. I'll let you know if I solve it.

Answer (score 1):

For Amazon, you should use gdx-pay-android-amazon.

This link explains why: https://github.com/libgdx/gdx-pay/pull/17